# Get Paragraph By Class In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to get the contents of a html paragraph in Javascript by identifying it by its 'class'. Here is a sample of what my HTML document looks like:

```
<html>
<p class="c"> <font> Here is the text I need to get  </font> </p>
<p class="c"> I don't need this text </p>
<p> Here is some more text </p>
</html>
```

I want to get the text in Javascript that says 'Here is the text I need to get'.

Any help would be appreciated :D

By the way, I cannot change the source of the page.

Comment: Btw,this is not in a browser. It is in a linux enviroment. More specifically the Karotz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = document.getElementsByClassName('c')[0].innerText
```

will yield the contents of the paragraph in the above example. But, class is seldom a good way to find the contents of a specific element. A class is a category of element and as such is often repeated on a page (hence the "0" in the above example: you have to specify *which* class `c` paragraph you want).

You're better off using an ID such as

> ```
> <p id="something">This is a specific passage</p>
> ```

which can be accessed using

```
text = document.getElementById('something').innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = javascript.getElementsByTagName('font')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML source code, and you know beforehand which specific paragraph you'll want to get using Javascript, you can assign an `id` attribute with a value unique to that page, then use the `document.getElementById(id of element here)` method.

Comment: Sorry, can't change the page source.

Answer (score 0):

Not that difficult:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("c")[0].innerText;
```

It reads as 'get the text of the first of all elements with class `c`'.